# Postfix not receiving mail

Tags: postfix-mta, webmin

I setup my Virtualmin using  the manual installation because I'm on Ubuntu 3.14 and the automatic install does not support this version.

Because of this now I have problems. Everything works except Postfix.

Here is my postconf -n:

```
ubuntu@web01:~$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = web01.redacted.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = web01.redacted.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_inet_interfaces
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

The error I get in the mail.log is:

```
Mar 22 08:17:49 web01 postfix/smtpd[27725]: connect from nk11p04mm-asmtpout002.mac.com[17.158.236.237]
Mar 22 08:17:50 web01 postfix/smtpd[27725]: 3ADDE65113: client=nk11p04mm-asmtpout002.mac.com[17.158.236.237]
Mar 22 08:17:50 web01 postfix/cleanup[27729]: 3ADDE65113: message-id=<4FD40961-2187-4B2C-8892-8A7A3BADD07E@icloud.com>
Mar 22 08:17:50 web01 postfix/qmgr[1263]: 3ADDE65113: from=<redacted@icloud.com>, size=1941, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 08:17:50 web01 postfix/error[27730]: 3ADDE65113: to=<redactedName@redacted.co>, orig_to=<hostmaster@redacted.co>, relay=none, delay=0.23, delays=0.2/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
Mar 22 08:17:50 web01 postfix/cleanup[27729]: 7083565115: message-id=<20140322081750.7083565115@web01.redacted.net>
```

And this is the /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
redacted.co redacted.co
hostmaster@redacted.co  redactedName@redacted.co
```

Here is the /etc/aliases:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
```

Comment: Please post the output of `postconf -n` and complete log lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the initial user in our case `redactedName` was not found. To solve this problem the user was manually added as per:

```
redacted.co redacted.co
hostmaster@redacted.co  redactedName@redacted.co
redactedName@redacted.co  redactedName
```

This fixed the problem.

I hope someone else finds this useful. It took a lot of debugging and looking at logs to finally understand what the error message was telling me was in fact the error itself. Basically  the `redactedName@redacted.co` was not being redirected to any user.